# Pushpin visibility property not working with converter

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a visibility converter that converts a bool to a Visibility enum, it is pretty straight forward. But for some reason it doesn't work with my `Pushpin`. My markup look like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EndPinTemplate">
        <maps:Pushpin CacheMode="BitmapCache" Background="{Binding Urgency, Converter={StaticResource UrgencyToColorConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      Content="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay}"  FontSize="14.667" Location="{Binding EndLocation}" 
                      Visibility="{Binding HasEndPoint, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                      DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <maps:Map>
        <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PushPins}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EndPinTemplate}" />
    </maps:Map>
</Grid>
```

It is only the `Visibility` property the converter doesn't work for. Setting it manually work, but I would like to do it with a converter. What should I do? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This *should* work, I would try debugging the binding. Have you tried breakpointing? is you value converter invoked?

Comment: that's the problem, I also think it should work and I have tried debugging but the converter is not invoked. hmm.

Comment: Does any binding work? What if you expose a Visibility property from the object that is bound to the pin?

Comment: I found the issue, I spelled the property name wrong. It's a little bit annoying that it doesn't trigger the converter or crash when that is the case. I would rather see a crash if I misspelled a property in the view than it defaults to a value.

Comment: Ahhh ... if you run in debug mode, you should see something in the output window that mentions the binding could not locate the source property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments to the question. The problem was that I misspelled a property name in the markup. So if you have a problem like this check the spelling.